# How to zip and encode in base64 an xml in Karate?

Tags: xml, base64, zip, karate, encode

let's say I have an xml from a file or saved in a variable in the feature file.

How do I zip it then encode it in base64 using Karate?

I tried using Java, but with no success:
I saved my xml in a variable first, then passed it to the Java methods below:

- `def xmlString = read('path/to/xmlName.xml')`

**First try**, I get the error that I cannot convert Xml to String -> Cannot convert 'xml content placeholder'(language: Java, type: com.intuit.karate.graal.JsXml) to Java type 'java.lang.String': Invalid or lossy primitive coercion.

```
    public static String encode64ZippedXml(String xml) throws IOException {
       File file = new File(xml);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
                int length;
                while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                zos.closeEntry();
            }
        }
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
    }
```

**Second try**, I get the same error as above:

```
    public static String zipEncodeXml (String xmlFile, String xmlFilePath) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);

        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(xmlFile);
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);

        byte[] xmlData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(xmlFilePath));
        zos.write(xmlData);

        zos.closeEntry();
        zos.close();

        byte[] zipData = baos.toByteArray();
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(zipData);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first Java method works. I just needed to pass it the relative path of my actual file instead of passing the karate variable "def xmlString = read('path/to/xmlName.xml')"

Comment: yes, for convenience there is also `karate.toJavaFile()` https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karate-tojavafile